# What is the difference between parsing betting website for live scores vs official website API?

Tags: api, parsing

I want to monitor some live scores on soccer matches. I have 2 ways to do this:

- official api from the website(free)
- parse websites source code myself and get data from it( need to do it every second)

What is the difference? Is calling API faster?

Answer (score 1):

This can depend on quite a lot external to this specific scenario, but given the context, yes the API's would much faster. The difference is in what data is being sent/received/parsed.

In either scenario you'd need some timer to tick and parse the results (website or API) so there's no performance difference in the "wait code", but the big difference will be in the data itself that is parsed. When you call the API, chances are more likely that you will send a specific parameter or call a specific function that indicates what you're looking for, pseudo-code example:

```
SoccerSiteApi.GetValue(SCORE, team1, team2);
```

Or

```
SoccerSiteApi.GetCurrentScores(team1, team2);
```

By calling the API, you are only sending and receiving a few hundred bytes (or more depending on data) and getting back exactly what you want, that is, you don't need to parse the scores out of the values sent back since they *are* the scores, so no processing time is spent doing anything additional with the data itself.

If, however, you were to parse the entire web site, you would need to make an HTTP `GET` request (and all that entails) to get the entire page (which could be a couple hundred KB or MB depending on content) and then spend processing time extracting the exact data you were looking for, and then doing this every second.

So the biggest difference is amount of data and time spent processing it.

Hope that can help